incorrect signature: void getDescribe() from the type Schema.DescribeFieldResult
For the following 2 lines I am getting getting the error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getDescribe() from the type Schema.DescribeFieldResult
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Schema.SObjectType.Case.fields.Type.getDescribe();

Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Schema.SObjectType.Case.fields.Subtype__c.getDescribe();

I do not understand the error. Seems Like Type is a reserved word.

Schema.sObjectType is a DescribesObjectResult, which is why you need to use fields to get to the fields. If you want to get the field token, use <sobjectType>.<fieldName>.
The two following pieces of code are equivalent with regards to the DescribeFieldResult variable.
sObjectField field = Account.Type;
DescribeFieldResult describe = field.getDescribe();

DescribeFieldResult describe = sObjectType.Account.fields.Type;


Well, Type is the name of a class (and not one of the reserved keywords), but that's not the issue here.
Schema.SObjectType.Case.fields.Type and Schema.SObjectType.Case.fields.Subtype__c are already of type Schema.DescribeFieldResult as demonstrated in the example of using fields in the DescribeSObjectResult documentation

Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Name;

DescribeFieldResult doesn't have a getDescribe() method (which makes sense, since it would just return itself).
The somewhat confusing bit is that while fields.<field api name> results in a DescribeFieldResult
fields.getMap() returns a Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>
So if you would use Schema.SObjectType.Case.fields.getMap().get('Type'), then you would need to follow that up with .getDescribe() to get the DescribeFieldResult.

It'd probably be nice to get some consistency from Salesforce here (you can get the SObject Field token from the DescribeFieldResult, and vice-versa), but this is probably behavior that a lot of customers depend on. So I wouldn't hold my breath on that being changed.

The newer sObjectType describe model was intentional (although confusing). It's not going to change because it's working as designed. To get an sObjectType token, you use <sobjectType>.sObjectType, to get a describe it's sObjectType.<sobjectType>. The docs could do better to call that out, though.
